# Find a finite morphism $F:X\to\mathbb{P}^k$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, morphism

I am working in the following problem from my algebraic geometry course:

**Let $X$ be a projective set of $\mathbb{P}^n$. Prove that there exists a finite regular morphism $F:X\to\mathbb{P}^k$, where $k=\dim X$.**

(In case of doubt finite means that $k[X]$ is  integral over $F^*(k[\mathbb{P}^k])$ and $F(X)$ is dense in $\mathbb{P}^n$, which is equivalent with $F^*$ injective)

Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks :)

Edit: Here is my attempt:

If $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ we are done, since we can take $F$ to be the identity. If $X\neq\mathbb{P}^n$ there exist $x\in\mathbb{P}^n\setminus X$, so we can consider the map $f_1$ as the maps that projects $X$ from $x$. If $f_1(X)=\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ we can take $F=f_1$. If $f_1(X)\neq\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ there exist $y\in\mathbb{P}^{n-1}\setminus f_1(X)$, so we can consider the map $f_2$ as the maps that projects $f_1(X)$ from $y$.  If $f_2(f_1(X))=\mathbb{P}^{n-2}$ we can take $F=f_2\circ f_1$,....

Since this process will end when we arrive $\mathbb{P}^k$ we can say that $F=f_{n-k}\circ\dots\circ f_{1}$. Of course this $F$ is well defined and it must be the solution to the problem, but I don't know how to prove that it is finite. If I can show that $f_i$ (a projection from a point) is a finite regular morphism we will be done, but I don't have ideas for this.

Edit: I know @KReiser said it could be a duplicate, but there the answer just work for characteristic $0$ and it gives us a 'geometric solution' that i don't like so much. I would like to have a pure algebraic solution and, if possible, an explicit formula for $F$ or a constructive method.

Comment: The map you describe is not defined at any point of $X$, all the coordinate functions vanish. You want to use Noether Normalization for this problem.

Comment: @Mentos Thanks, I added what I came up with, but I dont know how to finish from this.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679768/projective-noether-normalization

Comment: @KReiser yes and no, it is the same result but I would like a more algebraic solution, not just a simply geometric interpretation, which is more intuitive, but not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the more algebraic solution you're asking for. First, we should require that our base field is infinite - we could bypass this requirement if we were working in the affine/non-graded case (see for instance a very nice proof by Mel Hochster [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ehochster/615W10/supNoeth.pdf) which works over any field and in fact generalizes to arbitrary domains), but the structure of the argument we're using here does require this.

Let $k$ be an infinite field and let $R$ be a graded $k$-algebra which is finitely generated by $x_0,\cdots,x_n$ in degree one. Then there are $y_0,\cdots,y_m\in R$ so that each $y_i$ is a $k$-linear combination of the $x_j$, the $y_i$ are independent, and $R$ is finite over $k[y_0,\cdots,y_m]$. We prove this by induction on $n$: the base case where $R$ is generated by $x_0$ is clear, as either $R$ is a polynomial ring in $x_0$ or $R$ is finite over $k$.

For the inductive step, let $\varphi:k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]\to R$ be the obvious graded surjection. If $\ker\varphi=0$, we're done. Else, let $P\in \ker\varphi$ be a nonzero homogeneous element of degree $d$. I claim that up to a change of variables of the form $x_i=x_i+\lambda_ix_n$ and $x_n=\lambda_nx_n$, we may assume $P=x_n^d+\cdots$: writing $P$ as a polynomial in $x_0$ and expanding out after this change of variables, we have $$P=P(\lambda_0,\cdots,\lambda_n)x_n^d+\cdots$$ where the $\cdots$ represents terms of degree less than $d$ in $x_n$. As any nonzero polynomial over an infinite field has a nonzero value, we can find $\lambda_i$ so that $P(\lambda_0,\cdots,\lambda_n)\neq 0$ and therefore $k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]/(P)$ is finite over $k[x_0,\cdots,x_{n-1}]$ and surjects on to $R$. Now consider the image of $\varphi(k[x_0,\cdots,x_{n-1}])$ in $R$: by the previous sentence, $R$ is finite over this, and by induction, we can find an appropriate selection of $y_i$ so that $\varphi(k[x_0,\cdots,x_{n-1}])$ is module-finite over $k[y_0,\cdots,y_m]$. As the composition of finite extensions is finite, we're done.

Comment: Maybe I am stupid or something, but I understand what you did but I dont get why this implies the result...

Comment: This is the map on coordinate algebras corresponding to your projections. How familiar are you with the interplay between coordinate algebras and varieties?

Comment: I know the relation, but what I dont see is why this map correspond to a projection.

Comment: Let's look at $k[x_0,\cdots,x_{n-1}]\to k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ first. The preimage of the homogeneous prime ideal $(a_ix_j-a_jx_i)_{0\leq i\leq j\leq n}$ corresponding to the point $[a_0:\cdots:a_n]$ is $(a_ix_j-a_jx_i)_{0\leq i\leq j <n}$, which corresponds to the point $[a_0:\cdots:a_{n-1}]$. That's projection. The inclusion map $X\to\Bbb P^n$ is given on the level of rings by the surjection $k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]\to R$, and so the composite map is the projection of $X$ in to the $\Bbb P^{n-1}$ with $x_n=0$.

Comment: Right, now I get It, thank you for your nice answer.